# My discord bot is sending multiple messages after asyncio.sleep. How to fix this?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, python-asyncio

I have a code in which i remove afk after a certain amount of time. The user can send any no. of messages in this time but afk wont be removed, it will be removed only after a certain amount of time but my code just send as many messages sent by user as an embed of afk removed.

THIS IS MY CODE

```
if afkData.val() is not None:
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    db.child("AFK").child(str(message.guild.id)).child(str(message.author.id)).remove()
    em = discord.Embed(title="AFK removed",description=f"Your AFK was removed {message.author.mention}",color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255,20,147))
    await message.channel.send(embed=em)
elif message.mentions:
    for i in message.raw_mentions:
        AFK = db.child("AFK").child(str(message.guild.id)).child(str(i)).get()
    if AFK is not None:
        reason = AFK.val()["reason"]
        em = discord.Embed(title=f"User AFK",description=f"The Mentioned user is AFK....... **Reason: {reason}**",color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255,20,147))
        await message.channel.send(embed=em)
```

Here the if statement runs many times. Pls help me fix this issue

Comment: Here the asyncio.sleep() is causing the problem. are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Your indenting seems wrong, specifically whatever is supposed to be in the for loop, could you take another look at the code?

Comment: I want u to take a look at my if statement and tell why my bot send multiple msgs after asyncio.sleep() is over it sends multiple embeds

Comment: I don't exacly know, but i always fixing this problem (and i think it's not only because asyncio.sleep) by regenerating my bot

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), does it send multiple times just when you remove `asyncio.sleep(10)`? I dont think thats the problem here.

Comment: I want the user afk to be removed if he messages, but after a certain amount of time gap, but after asyncio.sleep(10) there are multiple messages saying afk removed.

Answer (score 0):

you're wrong in the code!

```
await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

will not remove AFK after a certain amount of time, it will just wait 10 seconds before to execute the other code.
So, I don't know how to suggest you a simple way to set the timer as you intend it for, but I can tell you that the code you write will not limit user command and/or remove AFK after some time. It will just wait 10 seconds after the user types

```
(prefix)(command)
```

. I hope I helped you, for any other info I'll be really happy to help you!